# paperclip, record is saved before a file saved on disk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, observer-pattern

I'm uploading an image and there is observer which is triggered when new record is created. In observer I'm pushing image via API to other service. 
Problem is when doing it locally or in rspec test, seems that record is saved in DB before image is saved on disk and I'm getting file not found error. How to make it to keep correct order ?

Answer (score 2):

Observers are triggered before callbacks defined in the model. Therefore the `after_create` method of your observer is invoked before paperclip's `after_save` method is run which processes the attachment.

Consider using [`after_commit`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html) or [`ar_after_transaction`](https://github.com/grosser/ar_after_transaction/blob/master/lib/ar_after_transaction.rb) instead of `after_save` etc. When communicating with an external API this is what you want anyway, since otherwise API calls can not be undone if the transaction is rolled back.

Comment: Having the same problem but according to: https://github.com/rails/rails-observers  

> This means that callbacks in an observer will always be called after callbacks defined in the model itself.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the internals of your observer and your code. A possible solution would be to change the observer to be triggered on the `after_create` event.

Comment: but it is after create at the moment